# $3$ quart from $10$, $5$ and $4$ quart

Tags: mathematics, decanting-problems

> Mr.Affison had two $10$ [quart](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quart_%28Einheit%29) containers full of wine. He also had a $5$ quart and $4$ quart measurement.
>
> All he wanted to do was to put exactly $3$ quarts into $2$ of his measurements.}Now he was standing there and wondering how he could do it!
>
> Then I offered him help and gave him some suggestions.

> #### Can you find out what my suggestion was and how many manipulations of pouring from one vessel to another, without did he require without wasting of any wine, tilting or other tricks?

Comment: If it is a duplicate, please tell me, I am not so good at searching duplicates. ;-)

Comment: Search for “jugs”

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First,

> Fill the 4 quart container. Then pour that into the 5 quart container and refill the 4 quart container.
>  10q has 2; 4 and 5 each have 4.

Next,

> Fill the 5 quart container from the 4 quart container, leaving 3 quarts in the 4 quart container.

The important step,

> Pour the 5 quarts into the 10 quart container, and then pour the 3 quarts from the 4 quart contaianer into the 5 quart container.
>  The 10 quart container has 7 quarts, the 5 quart container has 3 quarts, and the 4 quart container is empty.

Finally,

> Fill the 4 quart container from the 10 quart container, leaving 3 quarts in the 10 quart container.
>  Now the 5 and 10 quart containers both have 3 quarts, and the 4 quart container is full.

Comment: Nice answer, but there is one more.